# Not able to open a file in php

Tags: php, apache, file-io, permissions, fopen

The code chokes at fopen():

```
<?php 
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $fp = fopen("/path/to/file/some_file.txt","a") or die("can't open file");
  fwrite($fp,"some text");
  fclose($fp);
?>
```

And the resulting web page says:

"Warning: fopen(/path/to/file/some_file.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php on line 5
can't open file"

I tried to play with the file permissions, but to no avail. I changed the user/group with `chown apache:apache some_file.txt` and changed permissions with `chmod 755 some_file.txt`. Here is the relevant result of `ls -l /path/to/file/`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache 0 Apr 12 04:16 some_file.txt
```

Comment: `try chmod 777 some_file.txt` just to be sure - maybe your apache server isn't running as apache user? also, i assume your chown and chmod commands were referring to some_file.txt and not the test.php? your write permissions on test.php have no bearing on whether it can read/write some_file.txt

Comment: Yes, the chown and chmod commands were done on some_file.txt, I just messed up my question. Thanks, fixed it now.

I'll try 777, or 666 to be a bit safer, when I'm back at work, but I don't want to be doing that for every file I want to write to of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that even if Apache's been granted permissions to read the file, you also have to grant Apache access to ALL of the parent directories.

```
/path/to/file/
/path/to
/path
```

all need to grant Apache at least 'Read' permission.

Comment: i have the similar problem. Now the question is how do we give permission to apache for the specific paths?

Answer (score 3):

You're sure that `apache` is the user actually running your PHP?`

And: make sure that the `apache` user can reach `some_file.txt` in the file system and that it isn't blocked by some access restriction on directories above `some_file.txt`.

Comment: I'm not sure that apache is the user, it was just an educated guess, since I saw that apache existed. I wanted to try checking if apache can read the file. However, when I tried to su apache, it told me "This account is currently not available." Ideas?

Comment: my apache process is run by www-data, this is in ubuntu linux. If you're running your server on linux, type sudo ps aux | less to figure out who is running what.

Answer (score 2):

Before you go to fix an error, it would be nice to know, which error to fix.
Add these lines at the top of your script and then try again

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

PHP will tell you, what is the problem

Comment: Thanks. That confirmed it was an issue with permissions.

Answer (score 1):

`"a"` means you want to append, the same permissions as for write are needed.

You need at least 666 permissions to write by everybody. Or change file owner to server group (www-data on Ubuntu). And set the required permission.

Here is [Permission calculator](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/linux-commands/chmod.html)

If this does not helps, check the `safe_mode` too.